# CSS property not working with </div in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have written a css that will float a div when hover on it... it's working in Chrome and firefox but not in Safari.

Here is the Css:

```
.float {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
transition-property: transform;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 6px 6px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:0 6px 16px #000;
box-shadow:0 6px 6px #000;
}

.float:hover {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

And my html code is:

```
 <div class="float">
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
 </div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick glance, you're missing the closing bracket on your closing div tag.  Your HTML should look like this:

```
 <div class="float">
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
 </div>
```

I believe some modern browsers will assume that it's supposed to be closed and glance over the problem, which might explain the discrepancy between Chrome and Safari.

Hope that helps